# При установке robot js (npm i robotjs) выдаёт кучу ошибок

Tags: node.js, npm

Ошибка возникает только при установке `robotjs`, пробовал установить другие пакеты как: `npm i axios express`... все норм

```bash
>>> npm i robotjs

npm ERR! code 1

npm ERR! path D:\Programming\Projects\robotjs\node_modules\robotjs

npm ERR! command failed

npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild

npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok

npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@10.0.1

npm ERR! gyp info using node@21.5.0 | win32 | x64

npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.1 found at "C:\Python312\python.exe"

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS 

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.11.32929.386) found at:

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - missing any VC++ toolset

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2015 as it is only supported up to Node.js 18

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************

npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS

npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at VisualStudioFinder.fail 

(D:\Programs\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:113:11)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio 

(D:\Programs\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:69:17)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at process.processTicksAndRejections 

(node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at async createBuildDir 

(D:\Programs\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:69:26)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at async run (D:\Programs\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js:81:18)

npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22621

npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "D:\\Programs\\nodejs\\node.exe" 

"D:\\Programs\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" 

"rebuild" 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\Programming\Projects\robotjs\node_modules\robotjs

npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v21.5.0

npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.0.1

npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\murai\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-01-11T03_49_50_383Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows