Проблемы с RobotJS
Захотел установить Robots, прописав команды с их сайта - не получилось. Посмотрев пару гайдов - тоже не получилось. Решил залезть в нейронку. По её совету скачал Visual Studio Installer, через него установил "Visual Studio Build Tools" 2017 года и 2022.Node.js стоит самая совершенная, пробовал менять версию Python 2.7, 3.7, 3.1 -- не работает. Вот какие шаги проходят при установке:
Пишу в консоль "npm install -g node-gyp":
npm install -g node-gyp

changed 98 packages in 5s

16 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

Пишу в консоль npm install robotjs:
>npm install robotjs
npm warn deprecated npmlog@4.1.2: This package is no longer supported.
npm warn deprecated are-we-there-yet@1.1.7: This package is no longer supported.
npm warn deprecated gauge@2.7.4: This package is no longer supported.
npm error code 1
npm error path C:\Users\Admin\node_modules\robotjs
npm error command failed
npm error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
npm error node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252
npm error   throw err;
npm error   ^
npm error
npm error Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Admin\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js'
npm error     at Function._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1249:15)
npm error     at Function._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:27)
npm error     at TracingChannel.traceSync (node:diagnostics_channel:322:14)
npm error     at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:219:24)
npm error     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:170:5)
npm error     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:36:49 {
npm error   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
npm error   requireStack: []
npm error }
npm error
npm error Node.js v22.12.0
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: **ЕСЛИ НУЖНО ПРЕДОСТАВЛЮ .log**


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос. начните с заголовка.

Как я понимаю этот пакет устарел. Вот похожий вопрос с ответом.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1561120/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-robot-js-npm-i-robotjs-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%91%D1%82-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%87%D1%83-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA
